# Changing the value of a parameter in Angular 4

Tags: angular, observable

I'm building a unit test in Angular 4
I want to be able to pass in a variable to my router (as if I was on a webpage and navigating to `url/3` where `3` is the variable I'm referring to)

I have achieved this with the following

```
{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'id': 5}]) } },
```

What I want to achieve is, one test verifies that I query the proper database hit (through mocks) and that said object returns with ID `5`

In another test, I want to ensure that my component is listening to URL events.

How do I go about 'emitting' a change in this ActivatedRoute parameter so in another test, I can write `Parameter=10; expect returned object.id=10`

Comment: { 'params':  'id': <condition> ?  5 : 10 },

Comment: this code happens in my 'beforeEach' function so each test does not have the ability to set a variable at the time this gets executed